# Solr solconfig.xml missing

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat, solr

I have inherited a project which is using solr. When it loads it fails with this error:

```
   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'solr/collection1/conf/', cwd=/Users/andyarmstrong/Downloads/eclipse 15/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:316)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:281)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:103)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:117)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:971)
    ... 11 more

Mar 30, 2014 12:25:05 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core: collection1
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.recordAndThrow(CoreContainer.java:1654)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:1039)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$3.call(CoreContainer.java:629)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$3.call(CoreContainer.java:624)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config for solrconfig.xml
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:973)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:1033)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'solr/collection1/conf/',
```

In my projects I cannot find a solconfig.xml - and am struggling to determine where this file should be and what its contents by default would be.

I have found : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml which may give me a starting point but what directory in which JEE application am I placing this file? I have a solr project web app, and some other apps which appear to be classes only.

Please offer some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

As said in exception - Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or 'solr/collection1/conf/'

This article should help you to understand classloading in Tomcat - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Regarding to your question - only you know which project you use and which JEE application do you have. Anyway adding solrconfig.xml to classpath should help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can provide us with more details but any way you can download a sample of the Solr config file from [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml) and you should place that file under the relative path (solr/collection1/conf/) within your server directory (for example: Apache tomcat server then the relative directory will be under webapps directory).

If you provide us with more details, we can help you to overcome that exception.